# Hide Filter icon with column name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

We need to show Workflow History from Task List, so we drop a Filter (Query string) Web Part on SharePoint page. Filter Web Part working fine but it shows Filter icon with column name.

When we clear filter it shows all the records. we need to disable filter functionality after page load.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this CSS to `script editor` on your page

- Edit page.
- Add web part > script editor.

Add this CSS

```
<style>

.ms-filter-iconouter

{
display : none ! important;
}

</style>
```